# Where should my 3D character's pivot/anchor be?

Tags: unity, animation, blender, pivot, biped

I created a 3d character with some animations a month ago and when testing the character in my game, I notice there are some weird interactions with the scenery that have me worried, particularly when climbing slopes and jumping over ledges. My character is a humanoid biped and his pivot point is his pelvis (it was the first bone I made for the armature in Blender). Should I have moved the pivot to the bottom of his feet? Does it matter? My character does NOT use "use root transform" in Unity; He was animated "in-place" in Blender and forces move him around (including jump trajectories) in Unity

Comment: What sort of "weird interactions?" GIFs or video links would be helpful in diagnosing the specific problems. Often you can put the pivot anywhere as long as you account for that in the places where you'd need to pivot around a different point. It's a matter of understanding the kinds of operations you're going to do with the pivot in order to understand what would be the most convenient place.

Comment: I have no experience so I can share only what I saw recommend by people with experience. In relation to the skeletal animations the recommendation was the pivot to be close to the center of mass. If placed at bottom then leaning (say on running) becomes unrealistic, it becomed especially weird when fast changing directions. When stationary it is easy to assume that we just lean away from our position without moving. Instead what happens is we do 2 things: move position and rotate around the cener of mass (i.e. feets back and head forward).